# Protractor: text.indexOf(...).isDisplayed is not a function

Tags: node.js, protractor, aurelia, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

I'm aware this has been asked on a few occasions and even though I've looked through those questions, I'm not really sure how to fix this.

I'm checking if text "EUR" is contained in a div called "currency". This was working for me previously but I've started using lint and I've been getting a lot of these kind of errors.

This is the error I'm getting 
`Failed: text.indexOf(...).isDisplayed is not a function`

This is my code

```js
checkBuyerCurrency (text, buyerCurrency) {
    let currencyPromise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    const commonUtils = new CommonUtils();
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.className("currency")),     4000));
    var checkCurrency = element(by.className("balances"));
      checkCurrency.getText().then(function (text) {
           expect (text.indexOf("EUR").isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
           console.log("EUR only buyer");
      });
    });
  }
```

Do I need to make a `text` a variable or convert it to string? I'm not entirely sure how to do this due to the way I'm using the `Expect` statement

Thanks for any help

Comment: indexOf() will return a number or -1 if not present... .isDisplayed() is not a function of a number. This could work --
 expect(text.indexOf("EUR")).not.toBe(-1)

Comment: Thanks a million for the reply. If I wanted to change the expect to an if, so it would be something like... if <div currencies> contains "EUR"  // then do something//, any idea how I would implement that?

Answer (score 1):

"isDisplayed()" is valid function in Protractor API, but the working nature is like, it should be applied on web element to check whether element is displayed or not on UI.

**But**, your applying it on text which is type of number, that is not expected usage of isDisplayed(). if your requirement is to fail is text is not present do following.

```
checkCurrency.getText().then(function (text) {

       expect (text.indexOf("EUR")).toBeGreaterTha(-1);
  });
```

**OR**

```
 checkCurrency.getText().then(function (text) {
   if(text.indexOf("EUR")>-1){
    //do what do you want
    }else{
      expect (false).toBe(true);//it will make test case fail is EUR is not 
                                //present
      }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks a million for the reply. That works brilliantly.  If I wanted to change the expect to an if, so it would be something like... if <div currencies> contains "EUR"  // then do something//, any idea how I would implement that?

Comment: @Edmond can u mark it as correct answer if it works for you

Comment: @Edmond, i have updated the code. which will fulfill your requirement. Check it once

Comment: Thanks very much for your help

Comment: If I want to check if the div contains EUR but doesn't contain GBP, should I be able to do something like `else if(text.indexOf("EUR") >-1 && text.indexOf("GBP") <-1 //console.log("EUR only")` thanks.

Comment: Yes, update text.indexOf("GBP") <-1 to text.indexOf("GBP") =-1

Comment: Thanks for your help, when I try that I get an error `Expected a conditional expression and instead saw an assignment.`

Comment: Thanks so much, I had to use a third "="..... "text.indexOf("GBP")" ===-1 which seems a bit weird to me but it works.